# How can I change the value of an Oracle APEX page item using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I created the links in the left-most column to target a JavaScript function and I can successfully pass through the value of the row ID to that function.

[image]

Once clicked, a modal pops up to present a form to update the fields. However, I need the fields in the modal to be populated with the information from the row clicked. I figured I could create a hidden page item (P2_SONG_SELECT) to store the row ID so that I can use the value in my query for the data. My problem is I haven't been able to assign the row ID value to the application item.

Here is my JavaScript:

Each 'Edit' button successfully uses this URL target:

```
javascript:viewEditSong$(#Row_ID#).val();
```

to call this function:

```
function viewEditSong(Row_ID) {
  alert(Row_ID); // successfully alerts the Row ID
  $("#P2_SONG_SELECT").val() = UA_ID; // fails to assign
  $("#EditSongWindow").dialog('open'); // open the modal
}
```

**How do I properly assign the page item the value passed in?**

Elsewhere I use simliar syntax effectively:

```
ajaxRequest.add("P2_FILE_MAIN", $("#P2_FILE_MAIN").val()); // this works fine
```

Answer (score 2):

By 'application item' I presume you meant 'page item' as per your question title, since you're prefixing with page number.

Use this to set a value on the browser.

```
$s('P2_SONG_SELECT', 'xyz')
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/javascript_api.htm#AEAPI269

Answer (score 2):

Scott's post effectively solves your problem by using the built in APEX set method, but as an aside, you are attempting to use the jQuery `val()` method in the wrong way.

Instead of:

`$("#P2_SONG_SELECT").val() = UA_ID;`

You should use:

`$("#P2_SONG_SELECT").val(UA_ID);`

Have a look at the documentation for `val()`.

http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2

You can see that the usage of the function differs depending on whether you want to set or retrieve a value.